# Fortran: declare function and subroutine in "header module"

Tags: module, compilation, makefile, fortran

How can I **declare function** and **subroutine** in **separate module** and initialize it in the appropriate non-header module?

I am using *make* for compilation:

```
# All modules
OBJS        := $(BINDIR)/physics.o $(BINDIR)/particles.o

# Build rules
$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(VPATH)/%.f | $(BINDIR)
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(BINDIR)/%.mod: 

runner: $(OBJS)
```

.. and problem is that *physics.f* depends on subroutine in *particles.f* and vice-versa. So I can't just change order of compilation for these files.

I get such error:

```
src/physics.f:105.23:

      use particles
                   1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'particles.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make: *** [bin/physics.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Why would you make two modules that depend on each other?

Comment: There is nothing like headers in Fortran. Module dependencies cannot be circular. And `make`is not so good in making the right compilation order, especially if you do parallel compilations.

Comment: You must put your functions in the same module, and to handle circular dependency, use interface blocks. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532416/fortran-oop-circular-dependency-handling-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

While it is not totally clear what you intent to do it appears to me, that you are looking for [submodules](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Submodules).
Unfortunately they are currently not widely supported by compilers.

Comment: As far as I know only the Cray compiler supports them. For a comparative overview see http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status